# Pytorch Tabnet classifier to ONNX object

Tags: pytorch, onnx

I am training a pytorch-tabnet model and need to convert it to ONNX for production. ONNX can naturally convert torch.nn.module classes, but the TabNetClassifier is not directly supported. It looks one need to convert TabNetClassifier to torch.nn.module class as the first step.

Any other idea on the conversion is also appreciated.

I tried the direct conversion provided in torch.onnx but it fails as the classifier is not a callable, basically, in pytorch you can do "model(input)" but in TabnetCLassifier you gotta do "model.predict(input)"